# Change the order of options in a dropdown list based on the text 

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to change the options order in dropdown list

```
<select id="Genre" size="1">                  
        <option value="1">India</option>  
        <option value="2">US</option>  
        <option value="3">UK</option>  
        <option value="4">Africa</option>  
        <option value="5">Australia</option>  
        <option value="6">Newziland</option>    
</select>
```

Using javascript / jQuery I would like you to move the option named `"Australia"` as the second option.
Now its the 2nd last option. That means first option `India`, 2nd option `Australia` and then the rest of them.

I tried `$(#Genre>option[text=Australia].insertAfter('#Genre>option[value=1]')` But its not working..

Comment: What have you tried? jQuery's documentation is quite good: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I ask because $("#Genre option:eq(4)").after($("#Genre option:eq(1)")) will do the job, but is perhaps answering too narrow a question and isn't a very flexible solution

Comment: @ wheresrhys : I need to search based on text i added someting like 
`$(#Genre>option[text=Australia].insertAfter('#Genre>option[value=1]')`
but its not working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Genre>option[value=5]').insertAfter('#Genre>option[value=1]')
});
```

Or to get by content:

```
$('#Genre>option:contains(Australia)').insertAfter('#Genre>option:contains(India)');
```

Comment: i need to search based on text.I added like 
'#Genre>option[text=Australia]'  but its not working....

Answer (score 2):

Another variant:

```
$('#Genre option:eq(0)').after(function() {
    return $(this).parent().find('option:contains("Australia")');
});
```

Comment: I need to search based on text i added someting like $(#Genre>option[text=Australia].insertAfter('#Genre>option[value=1]') but its not working...

Answer (score 2):

Try this for a javascript solution:

```
var intCountry = '5';
var objSelect = document.getElementById('Genre');

//set initial node
var objInitialNode = objSelect.options[0];

//loop through options in select
for (var j = 0; j < objSelect.length; j++) {
    if (objSelect.options[j].value == intCountry ) {
        objSelect.insertBefore(objSelect.options[j], objInitialNode.nextSibling);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`$("option[value=5]").insertAfter('option[value=1]');`

if you wish to chagne the value also add the following:

```
$("option").each(function(index) {
      $(this).val(index+1)
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wrz4T/

Comment: I need to search based on text i added someting like $(#Genre>option[text=Australia].insertAfter('#Genre>option[value=1]') but its not working...

Comment: @Shebin you can use `:contains()` selector. Check the demo http://jsfiddle.net/Wrz4T/1

Answer (score 1):

if you know exactly what you want, and that move is the only one, you could do it like:

```
$('#Genre option[value=5]').insertAfter($('#Genre option[value=1]'));
```

then, to change the values to 1,2,3,4,5 (if you want)

```
$('#Genre option').each(function(i){
   $(this).val(i);
})
```